# What is the best way to repartition the system drive on a Windows domain controller?

Tags: windows, raid, partition, domain-controller, gparted

I have a Windows 2003 server that is the primary domain controller for the network.  It has a RAID 1 array that houses the 'C' and 'D' drives.  And a RAID 5 array that houses the 'E' drive.

The C:\ drive is 12GB in size and it is running out of space quickly.  The D:\ drive is 20GB in size and has 14GB of free space.

What I want to do is repartition 10GB from D:\ to C:.

Can I just boot the server using GParted and resize them?  Or is there something I need to be aware of considering that I am trying to repartition a system drive on a domain controller?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Whatever method you use, you start by making a full backup.  Modifying partitions may fail.

Comment: Absolutely.  I've had partitioning issues before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPARTD will indeed work fine, though you might also want to start thinking about swapping out your mirrored boot disks - are they really only 32GB each? sounds odd to me, must be an old machine (dual 36GB SCSIs? got to be 7+ years old I'm guessing), are you sure there's no unused space on that R1 array?

Comment: Yes, this is an old server (5+ years).  We can't replace it at the moment.

Comment: Understood, if you let me know the exact make and model I might have some larger spares you can have for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "special" about the NTFS volumes on a DC.  Haven't come across GPARTD, but have used Acronis Disk Director to effect a similar change.  However, I'm suprised that the boot/system volume is filling up, when it's 12GB in size.  Where is SYSVOL located?  Where's your pagefile?  Where's the AD DB/logs?  You might consider moving something first?

Comment: 12GB is ridiculously small for a Windows Server 2003 box, I'm not at all surprised its filling up. I generally go with a bare minimum of 20GB, depending on the role(s) the server is fulfilling.

Comment: Over the years, Windows updates seem to really fill up a drive. I've had similar problems on machines I thought would never hit 16-20GB and now I give the system partition a minimum 32GB.